# Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.defaul t-dispatcher-2]

Tags: scala, playframework, subproject

I'm trying to create subprojects using play-2.2.0 in eclipse but I'm facing error as per below details:

```
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.
default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' 
is enabled
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: views.html.main$.apply(Lcom.abc.core/sys/models/
Users;Lcom.abc.core/sys/models/Roles;Lplay/api/templates/Html;Lplay/api/templ
ates/Html;)Lplay/api/templates/Html;
    at com.abc.core.sys.views.html.index$.apply(index.template.scala:37)
~[classes/:na]
    at com.abc.core.sys.views.html.index$.render(index.template.scala:62)
~[classes/:na]
    at com.abc.core.sys.views.html.index.render(index.template.scala) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.abc.core.sys.controllers.Application.main(Application.java:144) 
~[classes/:na]
```

routes

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
# Delegate routes to sub-modules
-> / core.Routes
```

core.routes

```
# Home page
GET     /                           com.abc.core.sys.controllers.Application.index()
GET     /core                       com.abc.core.sys.controllers.Application.main()
```

Application.main() in package com.abc.core.sys.controllers

```
public static Result main() {
  return ok(index.render(Form.form(Register.class),
  Form.form(Login.class)));
}
```

index.scala.html

```
@(signupForm: play.data.Form[com.abc.core.sys.controllers.Application.Register], loginForm: play.data.Form[com.abc.core.sys.controllers.Application.Login])


@main(null) {   
  <div class="span3">
  </div>
  <div class="span8">
     <div class="well">
        @login(loginForm)
     </div>    
     <div class="well">
        @account.signup.createFormOnly(signupForm)
     </div>
   </div>    
}
```

main.scala.html

```
@(user: com.abc.core.sys.models.Users = null)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>PORTAL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"  href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @content
</body>
</html>
```

I got the error when I try to access `localhost:9000/core`.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Your `index.scala.html` template is calling another template function (`main.scala.html`). The error is telling you this doesn't exist. Does it?

Comment: I dont think so because I also have 'main.scala.html' template in my subproject(core). I just add it in main question.

Comment: okay. I found the solution. the problem is I cannot have the same file name of main.scala.html. Thanks Mikesname. Your suggestion gave me some hint.